# core data - check if in a NSSet exists a nsmanagedobjectID

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsset

I saw this answer and this is really what I need ([Does a Core Data NSSet contain an object with a certain ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256909/does-a-core-data-nsset-contain-an-object-with-a-certain-id)), but the used ID in there is a user customized ID. Is it possible to check if a object with a specific NSManagedObjectID exists in a NSSet? How can I do that with KVC?

Comment: Should work the same way

Comment: what do i have to write instead of bookID??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that

```
NSSet* mySetOfObjects;
```

contains your NSManagedObjects and you are looking for

```
NSManagedObjectID* specificObjectId;
```

the following should work:

```
[[mySetOfObjects valueForKeyPath:@"objectID"] containsObject:specificObjectId];
```